# error of library versions in gradle when importing graphview

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have android studio 3.3.2 and my goal is to import the GraphView library but, it turns out that it has given me an error that all the libraries must have the same version specification, I present an image of the error

[image: info]

---

error Tooltip info

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility
>   is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the 
>   latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  **Issue id: GradleCompatible**
>
> ---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mrl.fredy.estadistica"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: is it glans or `Gradle` in title?

Comment: Excuse me, it's gradle, you're absolutely right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
 compileSdkVersion 28 

 targetSdkVersion 28

 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Use

```
 compileSdkVersion 27

 targetSdkVersion 27

 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

GraphView library support library version is 27. 
 so you can downgrade your library version. if you do not want to downgrade then import GraphView as a module and in build.gradle file change to `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 28`

Comment: tank you, perfect solution